# Saving and Loading Image to IsolatedStorage Requires Saving Twice

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am using [ImageTools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com) from codeplex in order to save a canvas as a png; however, I had the same problem when I was using a `writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg()`. Therefore, the problem is not with the image type, but rather with how I am saving or loading in `IsolatedStorage`.

When I save the image by pressing a save button the file exists, but when I load the image nothing appears. If I save the image twice then the image loads and is displayed correctly.

Below is my code.

Saving File:

```
ExtendedImage myImage = myCanvas.ToImage();

using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (isoStore.FileExists("image.png"))
       isoStore.DeleteFile("image.png");

    using (var fileStream = isoStore.CreateFile("image.png"))
    {
        myImage.WriteToStream(fileStream, "image.png");
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Loading file

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (isoStore.FileExists("image.png"))
    {
        using (var fileStream = isoStore.OpenFile("image.png", FileMode.Open))
        {
            bi.SetSource(fileStream);
            this.img.Height = bi.PixelHeight;
            this.img.Width = bi.PixelWidth;
            this.img.Source = bi;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tryed your code and seems to be working fine, both on emulator as on device (Nokia Lumia 920)...

Comment: Odd. I have tried on both emulator and device (L920, Visual Studio 2012 targeting Windows Phone 8.0) and the error is persistant on both. Thank you for letting me know it works, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to retrieve the image from `isoStore`. It works for me.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
      if (iso.FileExists(string.Format("image.png")))
         {
            string fileName = "image.png";
            string filePath = iso.GetType().GetField("m_RootDir", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(iso).ToString() + fileName;
         }
}
```

You can set the source of the Image to filePath and you won't have any problem accessing it.

If this doesnt work, then the problem is while you are saving the image. You might have to find a workaround for saving the canvas to png or jpeg.